# How to fill color for one View of multiple view on button click ios?

Tags: uiview, uilabel, nsarray, nsdictionary, uiviewanimation

I need a progress bar like this. any leads?

[image]

Comment: this may help http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

Answer (score 0):

Crop out a minimal repeating part of the image like this (I did this sloppily, but to get the idea):

[image]

Make that a file in your project.  Call it, for example, `stripes.png`.  Now you can create a "color" with it, like this:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stripes"]];
```

And set any view's background color (provided the view doesn't manage it's own background, like many UIControls) like this:

```
someView.backgroundColor = color;
```

Alternatively, if you need an image rather than a color, you can make a resizable image like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stripes"];
UIImage *resizableImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
```

You can make this the `image` on an image view and layer that into the view hierarchy.